# Elasticsearch equivalent date pattern for java ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

In my pojo there is a LocalDateTime field which is formated with

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
```

I have to save the pojo in elasticsearch. What should be the relevant string pattern of this field in elasticsearch?
I tried the following

```
"action_time": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:sss"
}
```

When I print the field with ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME format in java I get this output

```
2022-08-04T16:29:09.866
```

What should be the proper pattern here?

Comment: Try `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"` instead of `"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:sss"`, which does not match at all starting with a single-digit month and day of month separated by slashes.

Comment: Your pattern works. Sorry i pasted wrong pattern, I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"format"` pattern in your JSON definition is not matching the one of `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` because it…

- does not include a `T` between date and time of day and
- contains 3 `s`, which would (possibly inpredictably) produce a three-digit value for seconds of minute, though those are limited to 59
- does not contain any symbol that outputs a fraction of second (should be `S`)
- uses lower-case symbols for hour of day, which is for 12-hour format and would require `AM` or `PM` somewhere in the output in order to be precise

Use this pattern instead:

```json
"action_time": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
}
```

You can read more about those pattern symbols in [the JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (here Java 9).